# Рандомное падение nginx

Tags: nginx

Который раз замечаю, что nginx как-то совершенно рандомно падает. Открыл логи и вижу:

```
Jun 21 00:15:08 vps447398 systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jun 21 00:15:08 vps447398 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:20 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:21 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 nginx[31502]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 21 00:15:22 vps447398 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Во-первых, почему nginx решил внезапно перезагрузиться? Во-вторых, как 80 и 443 порт могут быть уже заняты, если на них запущен nginx? Сделал `service nginx restart` и всё заработало.

Comment: Дамп включите, если падает оставит за собой `Core.xxx` файл. Собрать желательно (очень желательно) в Debug конфигурации, ключ например `-ggdb3`. И Сысоеву дамп отправить можно, не помешает. :) Вообще Nginx это отличный продукт, нет слов, но, с дебагом разных каверз в нем не просто отлавливать.

Comment: Чтоб красиво включить дамп не на всей машине, чтоб не разбираться чей это коре файл и почему их так много :) прямо в функцию `main` в Nginx добавьте следующее: `#include <sys/resource.h> struct rlimit cl; cl.rlim_cur = cl.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY; setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &cl);`

Comment: в логе написано, что процесс *nginx* не «падает», а **перезапускается** программой *systemd*.

Comment: Значит его нет? в списках процессов, вероятно.. В любом случае Nginx запускается второй раз, первая копия еще не выгружена из памяти, или процесс завершился некорректно, без закрытия сокетов, о чем и написано в логе. `ps axf` надо в этот момент глянуть, да и коре если появиться, то будет намного проще.